# Bitmap recycling in Android - when and where?

Tags: android, android-listview, bitmap, listviewitem, android-bitmap

I am unsure how to recycle bitmaps.

I have an app that displays lots of items in a listview. The problem is that the app crashes if i do not reduce the quality of the images in my ImageDownloader class.

In the code provided below, if i change options.inSampleSize = 4, the quality of the image is reduced and the app does not run out of memory. However, i would like to use high quality images without crashing my app.

How do i do that?

**Part of my ImageDownloader:**

```
static Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            String[] urlBits = url.split("/");
            Bitmap bitmap = MiscHelpers.getBitmapFromAsset(context, "animals/" + urlBits[urlBits.length-2] + ".jpg");
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
            return bitmap;
        }

        final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 1;


                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream,null,options);
                //final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                return bitmap;
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();  
                }
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException or IllegalStateException
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url + e.toString());
    } finally {
        if (client != null) {
            //client.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**My ListView Adapter:**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Inflate the layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, parent, false);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
    TextView firstline = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstline);
    TextView secondline = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.secondline);         

    // Get information about the report
    AnimalLocationLog current = objects.get(position);

    // Get all the important information
    String species = current.getSpecies();
    String sanitizedSpecies = MiscHelpers.sanitizeString(species);
    int reportId = objects.get(position).getTrackerId();

    // Construct the URL to the image
    String imageLocation = websiteUrl + sanitizedSpecies + separator + reportId + extension;

    // Display user report          
    downloader.download(imageLocation, image);          
    firstline.setText(species);
    secondline.setText("Spotted " + current.getDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd H:m"));          

    urlToPath = downloader.getUrlToPath();

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: It is a good practice to use the ViewHolder pattern. Also, you should load the image in background (the downloader.download method). Then, you can modify this method to receive the imageView and you can recycle the previous bitmap just before setting the new one. It worth reading: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html (if you did not it already).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything glaringly wrong. Perhaps there is something that can be done on the image editing side to make the images smaller?

I would recommend taking a heap dump and loading it into Eclipse MAT, https://www.eclipse.org/mat/, to get a complete picture of what is going on. In particular I would recommend looking at the Dominators report.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for your answer. I could make the images smaller, however, i still need to recycle the bitmaps, don't i?

Comment: I'm not sure that its necessary to recycle the bitmaps. According to this guide recycling is only mentioned for Gingerbread and lower, https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html#recycle. If you do want to try to recycle the bitmaps you should follow the advice in that article "You should use recycle() only when you are sure that the bitmap is no longer being used. If you call recycle() and later attempt to draw the bitmap, you will get the error: "Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap"."